# Is there a usable standards-compliant (168/286) portlet testing framework? (especially one that works with Spring PortletMVC)

Tags: unit-testing, spring, portal

I've not seen anything in this area I would recommend to a client.  If you've used Spring PortletMVC, how did you test it?

It's easy to test under the level of portlet code, and relatively easy to test on the client side through HtmlUnit, Selenium and the like, but I haven't seen anything that is a "Gray Box" test in the spirit of JSFUnit (which looks to me to be the way forward).

- Apache's [Pluto](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/subprojects/driver.html) driver could theoretically be used to bootstrap a test harness.  Has anyone tried this?
- Any stub or data provider approaches?
- Any approach to address two-phase processing concerns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know anything about portlets but here it goes.

There's [portletUnit](http://m0smith.freeshell.org/portletunit/docs/index.php).

> portletUnit is a testing framework
>   used to test JSR-168 portlets outside
>   portlet container just as servletUnit
>   is used to test servlets outside a
>   servlet container. The projected is
>   architected to map the functionally of
>   servletUnit onto portlets with
>   servletUnit itself providing the
>   foundation for portletUnit.

Some more related info could be found on his [Project PortletUnit blog](http://m0smith.freeshell.org/blog-portletunit/blogger.html), including [PortletUnit and Spring Portlet: Checking form validation errors](http://m0smith.freeshell.org/blog-portletunit/2008/04/portletunit-and-spring-portlet-checking).

> When testing with portletUnit, it is
>   not obvious how to check if there were
>   any form errors. Fortunately, using
>   the render listener feature of
>   `PortletRunner`, there is a simple way
>   to check for validator errors.

There's also a blog article written by Nils-Helge Garli Hegvik in 2007 titled [Testing Portlets with Jetty, Pluto and JWebUnit](http://portletwork.blogspot.com/2007/08/testing-portlets-with-jetty-pluto-and.html).

> Remembering an excellent article from
>   Johannes Brodwall's blog about
>   integration testing with Jetty and
>   JWebUnit, I wanted to extend his
>   approach to use the embedded
>   jetty-pluto setup I have created. This
>   turned out to be to be quite easy.

Finally, Spring Framework documentation [10.2 Unit testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch10s02.html).

> The
>   `org.springframework.mock.web.portlet`
>   package contains a set of Portlet API
>   mock objects, targeted at usage with
>   Spring's Portlet MVC framework.
>
> [...] The `org.springframework.test.web`
>   package contains `ModelAndViewAssert`,
>   which can be used in combination with
>   any testing framework (e.g., JUnit 4+,
>   TestNG, etc.) for unit tests dealing
>   with Spring MVC `ModelAndView` objects.
>
> [...] To test your Spring MVC Controllers, use
>   `ModelAndViewAssert` combined with
>   `MockHttpServletRequest`,
>   `MockHttpSession`, etc. from the
>   `org.springframework.mock.web package`.

Here's a related article written by John Ferguson Smart titled 
[Unit testing your Spring-MVC applications](http://java.dzone.com/blogs/mrjohnsmart/2008/02/03/unit-testing-your-spring-mvc-a).

> One of the great things about this
>   framework is how testable it is. In
>   Spring-MVC, any custom validators (for
>   field and form validation) and
>   property editors (for converting text
>   fields to specific Java types) are
>   dead-easy to test - you can just test
>   them as if they where isolated POJOs.
>
> Spring-MVC also comes with a full set
>   of mock objects that you can use (with
>   a bit of practice) to test your
>   controllers to your heart's content.
>   For example, you can use classes like
>   `MockHttpServletRequest` and
>   `MockHttpServletResponse` to simulate
>   your HTTP request and response
>   objects. This is also made easier by
>   the fact that `Controller`s can be
>   instanciated as normal Java classes.
>   For example, imagine you are testing a
>   controller class for a page that
>   updates a client details record. You
>   could do this very simply as follows:

```
public class UpdateClientTest {
        //
        // Prepare your request
        //
        request.setMethod("POST");      
        request.setParameter("id", "100");
        request.setParameter("firstName", "Jane");
        request.setParameter("lastName", "Doe");
        //
        // Invoke the controller
        //
    controller = new ChoosePeriodController();
        ModelAndView mav = controller.handleRequest(request, response);
    //
    // Inject any service objects you need
    //
        controller.setClientService(clientService);
    ...
        //
        // Inspect the results
        //
        assert mav != null;
        assertEquals("displayClient",mav.getViewName());  
        Client client = (Client) mav.getModel().get("client");
        assertEquals("Jane",client.getFirstName());  
        assertEquals("Doe",client.getLastName());  
    ...        
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I would say to skip the first suggestion. PortletUnit hasn't been touched in many years, there's no documentation for it at all that I can find and I'm not sure it will even work for the typical Enterprise setup.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout spring-test-portlet-mvc (https://github.com/markusf/spring-test-portlet-mvc), which exposes the features of MockMvc to the Portal context and lets you integration test your Spring Portlets easily.